# Are replacement MTB tire studs compatible between brands

Tags: tire, winter

I have a set of nokian gazza extreme studded tires, sometimes replacement studs can be difficult to come by at retail. Are the studs interchangable between brands typically or should I stick to only the studs sold by the same manufacturer as the tire?

Comment: FWIW. I was considering using the 45nrth studs since I can easily find them in 25 and 100 packs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [article](http://thegoldenwrench.blogspot.com/2010/11/replacement-studs-for-studded-tires.html) measures the sizes of studs between manufacturers. The upshot of the article is that if you have Nokian, Schwalbe, Continental, Innova studs, the dimensions are essentially the same and can be swapped around.

In any case, I'd expect Nokian (Suomi) studs to be the easiest ones to find these days anyway...

For reference, the essential from teh article linked above is that the studs are approximately:
"Overall height: 5.8mm (pointed), and 5.5mm (domed)

Base height: 1.0mm

Base diameter: 6.5mm

Shaft diameter: 3.4mm

Tip diameter: 2.0mm"

Comment: While dimensions are also important, I'd look at material as well.  Nokian use car grade studs, many companies use aluminum studs to save weight that don't last nearly as long as the steel car grade ones.

Comment: Who uses aluminum?

Comment: I think most of the "complained about" (by the LBS manager I worked with) were much cheaper knockoffier brands.  Everything on that list looks legit except for the Innovas.  It's possible it's changed too and no one makes them anymore since the conversation I remember is probably from 8+ years ago.  A couple of googles just failed to turn up any of the Chang Shen style knock offs I remember.

Comment: I've been buying studs from ebay to replace mine as they fall out (and when I got a pair of studded fat bike tires).They seem relatively good compatibility wise. I rarely have to replace more than a half dozen per tire per season. Probably mostly from riding dry roads when there isn't snow/ice.